# r renv is not start from a blank sheet, what is the default package list for it?

Tags: r, renv

I just noticed that for r's package `renv`, when you start a brand new project with `renv` init select or using renv::init() for a new blank project, it is not a blank sheet.

I mean if I create a new `.R` file and write these lines in it:

```
library(datasets)
library(base)
library(graphics)
library(grDevices)
```

the renv won't bother to inform me I used these packages and I need to install them or record them in `renv.lock`.

**My question is what is the complete set of these packages. which even I imported and used directly and `renv` will not notify me.**

And if `renv` decide it by dynamic loading the existing packages(seems not, even if I installed data.table in system lib path, If I use `data.table`, `renv` still immediately notice that and ask me to do proper action to deal with the inconsistency)

But how about the packages installed in the renv sandbox shared by all project? It seems `renv` notify me the package is installed but I still need to snapshot it into `renv.lock`.

Comment: What do you mean by “blank sheet”? What sheet?

Comment: @Konrad Rudolph I mean start from nothing included, white sheet? I didn't find a proper and vivid way to describe it.

Answer (score 4):

The packages you listed are all base packages, which are part of R.  They can't be updated without updating R.

You can get the full list of base packages using this code:

```r
installed.packages() |> 
  as.data.frame() |> 
  subset(Priority == "base") |> 
  rownames()
#>  [1] "base"      "compiler"  "datasets"  "graphics"  "grDevices" "grid"     
#>  [7] "methods"   "parallel"  "splines"   "stats"     "stats4"    "tcltk"    
#> [13] "tools"     "utils"
```

<sup>Created on 2024-03-15 with [reprex v2.1.0](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: I think this is right,  this path:   `renv::paths$sandbox()` will give you a folder, the library listed in this folder will be treated as installed whatever project you use, but not recorded, the package you list here are all used not bother by renv.